# How to implement an error message as well as success with this ember snippet?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript

I am working with this library, but have converted it to CoffeeScript: 
https://github.com/ryanto/ember-flash-message

Here is the code for the Coffee conversion I did:

```
Ember.FlashMessageController = Ember.Controller.extend
  queuedMessage: null
  currentMessage: null
  message: Ember.computed.alias "currentMessage"
  now: ->
    @setProperties
      queuedMessage: null
      currentMessage: @get "queuedMessage"

Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper "flashMessage", (options) ->
  template = options.fn
  container = options.data.keywords.controller.container
  controller = container.lookup("controller:flashMessage")
  parent = Ember.ContainerView.extend(hideAndShowMessage: (->
    currentMessage = @get("controller.currentMessage")
    view = if currentMessage then Ember.View.create(template: template) else undefined
    @set "currentView", view
  ).observes("controller.currentMessage"))
  options.hash.controller = controller
  options.hashTypes ||= {}
  Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call this, parent, options

Ember.Application.initializer
  name: "flashMessage"
  initialize: (container, application) ->
    container.register "controller:flashMessage", Ember.FlashMessageController

Ember.FlashMessageRouteMixin = Ember.Mixin.create flashMessage: (message) ->
  controller = @controllerFor "flashMessage"
  controller.set "queuedMessage", message
  controller

Ember.Route.reopen Ember.FlashMessageRouteMixin,
  activate: ->
    @_super(arguments)
    controller = @controllerFor("flashMessage")
    routeName = @get("routeName")

    # do not display message in loading route, wait until
    # any loading is done.
    controller.now() if routeName isnt "loading"
```

As it is now, in the route I am using I have to call the .now() function due to the lack of a route change to trigger the message in the part of the application I am using it. Here is the code for that piece:

```
.catch (response)=>
    Ember.Logger.error 'Error Message', response
    window.alert "Sorry, there was an error. Please try it again"
    controller.get('model').transitionTo 'uncommitted'
  .finally ()=>
    controller.set 'isSubmitting', false
    Ember.run.later(@, (=>
      @flashMessage('').now() # set flash msg to empty string so it disappears after 5 seconds
    ), 5000)
```

I simply want to be able to add another class of flash messages and then be able to have one styled for errors. I tried making a messageType in the controller and it was failing to work. Any ideas on the best route of implementation? I know this is pretty hacky as it sits already and just want to get it functional and polish later.